# Los if no funcionan como quiero. A veces muestran el mensaje correctamente, pero casi siempre no muestran nada

Tags: java, java-swing

```
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Video30_Adivina_numero {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numeroRandom = (int) (Math.random()*100);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "\tBienvenido a adivina el número.\nUsted deberá adivinar un número del 1 al 100 generado "
            + "aleatoriamente en la menor cantidad de intentos posible.");

    int opcion;

    boolean salir = false;


        do {
            opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Seleccione una opción digitando el número correspondiente.\n1.Adivinar\n2.Salir"));


                switch (opcion) {

                case 1: //Adivinar


                    int numeroIntentos = 0;

                    int numeroRecibido = 0;

                    int diferenciaMayorNumero = numeroRandom - numeroRecibido, diferenciaMayorRecibido= numeroRecibido - numeroRandom;

                    do {

                        numeroRecibido = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digita el número que crees que es."));


                        if (numeroRecibido == numeroRandom) 
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡¡Has acertado!!!!\n"+"Número de intentos: "+numeroIntentos );
                            if (numeroIntentos <=5) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"¡Eres un crack en este juego! Lo lograste en 5 intentos o menos.");

                        } 

                        else if (numeroRandom > numeroRecibido)
                        {

                        numeroIntentos++;

                        if (diferenciaMayorNumero >= 50) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrectísimo. No sea miserable, súbale un montón.");

                        else if (diferenciaMayorNumero >= 20) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Sea tacaño, le falta subir bastantico");

                        else if (diferenciaMayorNumero >= 10) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Pero ya casi compa, suba.");

                        else if (diferenciaMayorNumero >= 1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. UYYYY rata, casi casi. Súbale ahí.");

                        }//else if 1

                        else if (numeroRecibido > numeroRandom) 
                        {

                        numeroIntentos++;

                        if (diferenciaMayorRecibido >= 50) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrectísimo. Se la voló. El número no es tan big.");

                        else if (diferenciaMayorRecibido >= 20) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Bastantito volado, intente más abajito.");

                        else if (diferenciaMayorRecibido >= 10) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Intenta un poco más pa'bajo");

                        else if (diferenciaMayorRecibido >=1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Intenta un pelín más pa'bajo");


                        } //else if 2

                        else if (diferenciaMayorNumero ==0 && diferenciaMayorRecibido ==0)JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"¡¡Felicidades!!");//else if 3



                    }while(numeroRecibido != numeroRandom);


                break;//Lo quito para que siempre muestre el marcador al final


                case 2: //Salir

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Gracias por jugar.");

                salir = true;

                break;

                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opción incorrecta");

                }//switch


        }while (salir == false);


}//main


}//class
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit] para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [help/on-topic]. También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Agrega una explicación en tu pregunta de cual sería el comportamiento esperado, revisa [ask],saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He notado que si el número tanto en los if si el número es **mayor** como si es **menor**, tienes lo mismo, es decir, en todos los if estás evaluando digitado sea menor que el número a adivinar

Por lo mismo cuando el número digitado es **mayor** al número a adivinar los if no trabajan

Por lo mismo tendrías que modificar tu código de los if `diferenciaMayorNumero >= 50` con el signo de **mayor,** como lo siguiente:

```
else if (numeroRecibido > numeroRandom) 
{
     numeroIntentos++;

     if (diferenciaMayorRecibido <= 50) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrectísimo. Se la voló. El número no es tan big.");

      else if (diferenciaMayorRecibido <= 20) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Bastantito volado, intente más abajito.");

     else if (diferenciaMayorRecibido <= 10) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Intenta un poco más pa'bajo");

     else if (diferenciaMayorRecibido <=1) JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrecto. Intenta un pelín más pa'bajo");

} //else if 2
```

Me comentas como te va

Comment: Antes que nada, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La cosa es que yo hice dos variables como puedes ver, las cuales se llaman diferenciaMayorRecibido que es el número recibido menos el número aleatorio, y otra que se llama diferenciaMayorNumero (me va acabo de dar cuenta que es un nombre ambiguo) la cual es el número aleatorio menos el número que se está recibiendo, y en el else if cuando el número recibido es mayor uso la variable diferenciaMayorRecibido, y cuando el mayor es el número aleatorio utilizo diferenciaMayorNumero. Acabo de hacer una prueba, adiviné el 99 y solo el primer if funciona

Comment: Ya hice el cambio que me dijiste y sí funciona (excepto que aún muestra sieempre el primer mensaje), aunque aún intento entender por qué jaja.